# How can I reuse component logic

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a custom table that will have pagination, filtering, sorting, and other common features. I do not want to use an existing solution, both because this is a good exercise to get familiar with React and because I want the table tailored to my needs.

The issue I'm running into is with the filtering. What I want is to put the "does object pass filter" logic in the Filter; I've used this pattern successfully in other languages and it's very clean.

However, with React all of the logic has to go in the parent because the parent can't call methods on the child. So I'm stuck.

Here's what I want to do, roughly.

```
class FilterContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);

    this.state = { isOpen: false };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <FaFilter id="filter-icon" />
        <Popover placement="right" isOpen={this.state.isOpen} target="filter-icon" toggle={this.toggle}>
          <PopoverHeader>Filter table</PopoverHeader>
          <PopoverBody>
            {this.props.children}
          </PopoverBody>
        </Popover>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
};

class Filter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);
  }

  setValue(event) {
    this.props.setValue(this.props.name, event.target.value);
  }

  // I want this as a method on the filter because I will have different types of
  // filters, and I don't want to duplicate this everywhere I use a filter
  passesFilter(obj){
    if (obj.hasownproperty(this.props.name)){
      if (obj[this.props.name].contains(this.props.value)){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Label>
          {this.props.name}

          <Input
            id={this.props.name + "-value"}
            type="text"
            value={this.props.value}
            onChange={this.setValue} />
        </Label>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
};
```

But now imagine instead of Filter, I had a StringFilter which could handle case sensitivity and regex, a BoolFilter which is just true/false, maybe a DateFilter, etc. Each one of those has the concept of "passes filter", and duplicating them in the DataTable as well as anywhere else I want to use them sucks.

Hopefully this makes sense, if not I can provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter library function and import some and stack the filter result 
For example

```
Filter/Date
myFilterDateBetween(DateA, DateB, DateC){ 
  //true false
}
myFilterDateBefore(DateA, DateB){ 
  //true false
}

// other DateFilter

Filter/Boolean
filterIsTrue(Bool){ 
  //true false
}

// other BooleanFilter

Filter/...type
//other filter base on type:
```

And after import filter where you need it and call them

```
import myFilterDateBetween from 'Filter/Date'
import MyOtherFilterBoolean from 'Filter/Boolean'

data.filter( 
   (item)=>myFilterDateBetween(item.date,dateA, dateB)
).filter(
    (item)=>MyOtherFilterBoolaen(item.Boolean, true)
)
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: That means I have to keep the logic separate from the component, thus maintaining the component in two spots. I'm hoping someone can point me to a way to have it all in one place.

Comment: You can also create an HOC and pass in props the filter name and the data fields to apply the filter

Comment: I'm not seeing how a HOC accomplishes the reuseability I'm after. Do you have an example?